# Login with facebook inside fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, facebook-graph-api

[image: after login it has to look like this image]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    String[] fragmentTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bottom_nav);
        mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnChildClickedListener(new OnChildClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildClicked(int child) {
                selectFragment(child);
            }
        });
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectFragment(0);
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(int child) {
        switch (child){
            case 0:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, HomeFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, SearchFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, ProfileFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                Log.d("Activity", "ON RESULT CALLED");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Profilefragment.java

```
    public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {


    public static final String ARG_TITLE = "titleArg";
    public static final String ARG_INDEX = "indexArg";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.120:3002/new_user";
    LoginButton loginButton;
    TextView textView;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String title, int index) {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putInt(ARG_INDEX, index);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        //((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE));
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_actions.music", "user_actions.video", "user_actions.news","email,user_hometown","user_religion_politics","user_likes","user_status","user_about_me","user_location","user_tagged_places","user_birthday","user_photos","user_videos","user_education_history","user_posts","user_website","user_friends","user_relationship_details","user_work_history","user_games_activity","user_relationships"));
        textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            /*GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        "/me/friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                    textView.setText("Login Success \n" +response);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {

                                }
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();*/
                textView.setText("Login Success \n"+
                        loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()+"\n"
                        +loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()+"\n"+loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());


                final String token =  loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString();

                JSONObject jsonBodyObj = new JSONObject();
                try{

                    jsonBodyObj.put("accesstoken", token);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final String requestBody = jsonBodyObj.toString();

                JsonObjectRequest JOPR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                            System.out.print(URL);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                                    requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }


                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                requestQueue.add(JOPR);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                textView.setText("Login Canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("FRAGMENT", "onResultCalled");
    }

}
```

Updated Logcat

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at com.example.prateek.bottomnavigation.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:74)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3387)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3434)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

While running this inside fragment code getting an error but if I'm running this same code inside any activity then it works fine. I'm trying to get the issue resolved but unable to get a solution please help me.
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize Facebook Sdk in `onCreateView` at the begin..

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
```

Also you need to inflate the layout and find your element using

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false); 
loginButton=(LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
```

**Use this code:**

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        callbackManager= CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        //((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE));
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        loginButton=(LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
//        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_actions.music", "user_actions.video", "user_actions.news","email,user_hometown","user_religion_politics","user_likes","user_status","user_about_me","user_location","user_tagged_places","user_birthday","user_photos","user_videos","user_education_history","user_posts","user_website","user_friends","user_relationship_details","user_work_history","user_games_activity","user_relationships"));
        textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            /*GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        "/me/friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                    textView.setText("Login Success \n" +response);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {

                                }
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();*/
                textView.setText("Login Success \n"+
                        loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()+"\n"
                        +loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()+"\n"+loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());


                final String token =  loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString();

                JSONObject jsonBodyObj = new JSONObject();
                try{

                    jsonBodyObj.put("accesstoken", token);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final String requestBody = jsonBodyObj.toString();

                JsonObjectRequest JOPR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                            System.out.print(URL);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                                    requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }


                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                requestQueue.add(JOPR);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                textView.setText("Login Canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Also Your `onActivityResult()` will not work ...you need to add `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

in your **fragment:**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("FRAGMENT", "onResultCalled");
    }
```

And your parent **activity** add: otherwise the `onActivityResult()` of fragment will not be called.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                Log.d("Activity", "ON RESULT CALLED");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added the same code as you said above but I'm getting this D/ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException can please help me once again

Comment: post the logcat error in question ...where are u getting the exception?

Comment: I have posted both the main activity and profilefragment code with logcat. please see to it thanks :)

Comment: use `for (Fragment fragment : getFragmentManager().getFragments())`...and post the full logcat..

Comment: see the updated log cat above I have added e.printStackTrace() **public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                Log.d("Activity", "ON RESULT CALLED");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }**

Comment: The error is pointing on 74 line MainActivity which fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

Answer (score 2):

use this code in Activity not in Fragment

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.com_facebook_fragment_container);
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

in Fragment add

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By using your code getting an error  **java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.prateek.bottomnavigation/com.example.prateek.bottomnavigation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: initialize fragment with your Fragment and remove  if(FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {    condition

Comment: please update your activity code and also adapter code.

Comment: I am not using any adapter and I have updated the code. After the successful login i will use the adapter to display the values ryt now I m just using text view to print the id and name.

Comment: that I have already added in the question i.e Profilefragment

Comment: Callback for me is never called

Answer (score 0):

Your error says `loginButton` is null, you have used reference of `container` to create object of `LoginButton` instead of this create a object of `View` at the beginning of `onCreateView()`

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
```

Now take reference of this `view` whenever you are accessing any control/widget from xml, like

```
loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
```

Make it for other objects also and your return statement should be

```
return view;
```

Comment: I tried by creating view but I was getting an error. let me try once again by creating a view.